# Browser closes after project's cache cleaned [symfony2]

Tags: symfony, caching, symfony-console

I have a project in symfony 2.3.
I had to clean it's cache to free some space of my server. But after I didn't the browser doesn't even load the page as before. It goes to the link and after it closes without any response.

I don't know which informations are useful to this problem. I had just ran the command:

```
sudo php app/console cache:clear
```

Must I clean the cache for the prod environment too?

Is it dangerous to the project to clean the cache of the project? I always think that may crash the whole thing.

Thank you

Comment: what is the error displayed ?

Comment: assign chmod 777 to the var/cache directory

Comment: Yes you always need to clear the cache for the production environment after making changes.  Will it crash the 'whole thing'? Possibly.  Depends on traffic and what not.  Take the app offline if this is a concern.  For my apps, it has not been a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the permissions of the cache directory and also move your sessions in a separate folder, because a cache:clear also logout any logged user if you don't handle the sessions directory.

```
framework:
    session:
      # Don't forget creating the folder /var/sessions with the right permissions
      save_path: %kernel.root_dir%/var/sessions
```